# Find unknown vertices from two sides of right angled triangle and one vertex

Tags: math, geometry

Consider a right angled triangle. The opposite side and adjacent side lengths are known. Also one vertex coordinate is known and angles are known. How to find other two vertex points?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

-For a 3d triangle, you need at least a point and 2 vector (with proper lengths).

-For a 2d triangle, you need at least another point or 1 vector.

[image: Sketch of different triangles all being the same]

Comment: I'm sorry. I have edited the question. The angles are also known.

Comment: No problem, but I'm afraid you still can't. 
In 3d, you would still need at least 1 point or vector to build the 'plane' on which the triangle will reside, and in 2d you would still be able to rotate the triangle anywhere around the vertex, meaning you still can't have a 'final' position.. UNLESS the angles you talk about are not angles of the triangle, instead they are angles relative to something else (e.g. the x-axis vector)

Comment: In 2 d also cant?

Comment: @rishu1992 I've just edited my answer with an image. You can rotate the triangle around the vertex it will still have the same internal angles and sizes, but it's still a valid candidate given the parameters you have. PS: i didn't intend to draw a fan =D